# How do you get the Generalist badge?

Tags: support, badges

Can somebody explain for what activities users get the **Generalist** badge, because I didn't understand its short description.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/4228).

Comment: You may find [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119518/generalist-badge-progress-toward-with-improved-sort?userid=256196) useful (tweak that first top 50 to 40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the short description for the badge.

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

This means that you must achieve a 15 total score on your answers to questions that have one of the top 40 tags on a particular site. If you accomplish this for 20 of the tags in the top 40 of that particular site, you will receive the badge.

It is only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has over 200 questions

Comment: That's not quite how I read that description.  From my reading, I can get the badge as long as the total score over *any number of answers* adds up to 15 in each of 20 of the top 40 tags.  Your answer indicates that I need to nail *an* answer (+15) in 20 tags.  Could you or someone else confirm/deny?

Comment: @John: You're correct.

Comment: @Josh - And what is the definition of ***`top`***?

Comment: Does top means e.g. [top of this list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags)?

Comment: @user2623967 I believe so

Comment: @John You are actually correct.

Comment: "points" is a bit ambiguous. It's not reputation gained, but sum of (upvotes - downvotes).

Comment: I agree but it is nearly impossible to get 15 points total anyways and that wouldnt be called points but actually reputation